# AFNetworking NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9834) in iOS11

Tags: afnetworking, ios11

use AFNetworking 3.1 post in iOS11 i got this:

```
    2017-09-21 14:48:17.086770+0800 FlashPay[1861:756422] TIC TCP Conn Failed [6:0x1c016b7c0]: 3:-9834 Err(-9834)
    2017-09-21 14:48:17.191937+0800 FlashPay[1861:756422] TIC TCP Conn Failed [7:0x1c41684c0]: 3:-9834 Err(-9834)
    2017-09-21 14:48:17.286800+0800 FlashPay[1861:756889] TIC TCP Conn Failed [8:0x1c416ac80]: 3:-9834 Err(-9834)
    2017-09-21 14:48:17.287057+0800 FlashPay[1861:756889] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9834)
    2017-09-21 14:48:17.287108+0800 FlashPay[1861:756889] Task <6558B73B-719E-4A5B-B73B-43A01CE7B4A4>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1205 [3:-9834])
    2017-09-21 14:48:17.287513+0800 FlashPay[1861:756890] Task <6558B73B-719E-4A5B-B73B-43A01CE7B4A4>.<1> finished with error - code: -1205
    YMTLoginViewController.m:102    login failed:Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1205 "server“meyserver.com”do not accept certificate。" UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x1c0300630>,                         
   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9834, NSUnderlyingError=0x1c4651970 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1205 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9834, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=(
   "<cert(0x1568e8800) s: meyserver.com i: meyserver.com>"
   ), _kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=2, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x1c0300630>, _kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificates=(
   "<SecIdentityRef: 0x1c4238ca0>",
   "<cert(0x155ea5cd0) s: meyserver.com i: meyserver.com>"
   ),_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9834}}, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(
   "<cert(0x1568e8800) s: meyserver.com i: meyserver.com>"
   ), NSErrorClientCertificateChainKey=(
  "<SecIdentityRef: 0x1c4238ca0>",
  "<cert(0x155ea5cd0) s: meyserver.com i: meyserver.com>"
  ), NSLocalizedDescription=server“myserver.com”do not accept certificate, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://myserver.com:5843/,  NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=2}
```

but it works well in iOS10 and iOS9.3, please help me.

Comment: Could you please copy and paste the Log into the question? That way it will be better to read and analyze the logs. Better than an image. Also it will be helpful if you provide us with the code causing the error.

Comment: @Orlando I've pasted the log into the question, please check it. If you need more information, please let me know. Thank you very much.

Comment: There are a lot of possible causes for this error. It may be the server TLS certificate or settings. Apple did some changes on the supported Ciphers, so take a look on this: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207828 Also, I recommend you to follow the discussion on this AFNetworking Issue: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/3999

Answer (score 0):

iOS11 had some changes：[support.apple.com/en-us/UT207828](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207828)

My server did changes which based on this, then my code work well.